# Set value of a range using array when filter present

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, autofilter

I want to get the values of a range into an array, work on the array data, and then set the values in that array back into the range it came from, considering that the range may contain some hidden rows.

Let's take an example of a sheet of two columns:

```
----A-------B-----
    VALUE | FILTER
    1     | P
    2     | N
    3     | N
    4     | P
    5     | P
```

Then you apply an auto filter and set the B column to show only cells with "P", that will hide rows 3 and 4.

I get that range like this:

```
Sub WorkRange()
    Dim R As Range

    Set R = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A6")
    Values = R.Value

    Values(1, 1) = "New 1"
    Values(2, 1) = "New 2"
    Values(3, 1) = "New 3"
    Values(4, 1) = "New 4"
    Values(5, 1) = "New 5"

    R.Value = Values
End Sub
```

That code will get the values from A2 to A6, including hidden rows filtered out by the AutoFilter definition. When I try to set the value of that range with the changed data, it leaves hidden rows unchanged and sets visible cells (cells A2, A5 and A6) to "New 1".

I want to set the values in that range regardless of the row state.

I have some sheets with thousands of rows. If I change using .Cells, row by row, it takes too long. Using Arrays to set the Value of a Range is much faster, and it works in cases where a filter is not present.

Comment: Can you unfilter first and reapply the filter after you have pasted the new values?

Comment: I'm actually not working directly with VBA Macros, I'm using a COM object in Delphi to work on the sheets. And since there are many new files I receive, with many different filters,it would be nicier if I could go around that problem without changing the sheet filters. It will take some manual work that I could avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the array result into a different sheet and refer those range in fomula with `vlookup` or `=refercells`

`range("A2:A"&lrow).formula = "=sheetnamecell"`

This is the only way to  apply the array result back to the filtered range. If the array range is not filtered  you can just apply the result directly to the range.