# Data corruption using VBA array function on filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

Take a very simple spreadsheet

[image]

Run the following code on it. It just copies the sheet to an array and then back again. It should not make any difference to the sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim vArr As Variant
    
    ' Copy the contents of the sheet to a 2D variant array
    vArr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    
    ' Copy the variant array back to the sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vArr, 1), UBound(vArr, 2)) = vArr
    
    ' There should be no difference to the sheet
End Sub
```

All works fine.  Now filter the sheet and exclude row 2 (or indeed any other row)

[image]

Run the code again and you get a mess:

[image]

Is this a bug or is there some deeper philosophy at work here? Is there a way round this, short of clearing the filter.

**UPDATE**
I would also note that there is a difference between hidden rows and filtered rows.  If you hide a row then the code works fine.  It seems to be only to do with filtering.

Comment: It would [appear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43553574/11683) to be one of peculiarities of `.Value`, where what it returns (the entire array including hidden rows) is not what it is willing to accept (ignoring the filtered rows).

Comment: Somewhat irrelevant but should it not be `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vArr), 3)` ?

Comment: @QHarr I believe the idea is to only update the first two columns. It is indeed irrelevant because the problem happens with an intermediate `Redim Preserve vArr(1 to 4, 1 to 2)` too.

Comment: Agreed irrelevant for effect. I didn't realise intention was to only update two columns. My bad.

Comment: @QHarr.  You're right, I have updated the question but the problem persists.

Comment: @GSerg.  Thanks - I didn't find that post although it doesn't appear to have been resolved.  I tried with `.Formula` instead of the implicit `.Value` but result is no better.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your VBA script to use for loops you can get around this issue.

Slightly modifying your VBA script I did not see the issue you mentioned above.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim vArr As Variant
    
    ' Copy the contents of the sheet to a 2D variant array
    vArr = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion


    ' Copy the variant array back to the sheet
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vArr, 1), UBound(vArr, 2)) = vArr

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    
    For row = 1 To UBound(vArr, 1)
    
        For col = 1 To UBound(vArr, 2) 
            'Debug.Print vArr(row, col)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col) = vArr(row, col)
        Next col
    Next row
    ' There should be no difference to the sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: - unfortunately that approach also removes all the performance improvements from using a variant array.  For large tables the difference is dramatic.