# Excel VBA set values on filtered range unexpected results

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy values from one Excel column to another using VBA.  To do it efficiently I use `Range.Value`.  This works fine, except when the source range is filtered.

Sample VBA:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Range("D2:D4").Value = Range("B2:B4").Value
End Sub
```

Run on this simple sample Worksheet produces the expected results:

[image: Sample worksheet, unfiltered]

Now filter the `Source` column to exclude values `B`.  Running the `Test` VBA produces the following:

[image]

Cell D4 should have value `C`, not `A`.  (Extending the sample data and filter produces more bizarre results when doing a `Range.Value` assignment.)

WTF is going on, and what reasonable VBA will do a correct copy of values when source data are filtered?

Comment: Copy/paste the visible cells `(SpecialCells xlVisible)`. Example of how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60660686/6706419)

Comment: @BigBen Can you clarify?  The value assignment works fine for column ranges in every case I have tried that doesn't involve filtered rows.

Comment: @feetwet thats the point. Value transfer only works in a continuous range. You have a non-continuous range i.e. rows are skipped

Comment: @urdearboy – So the object Range("A2:A4") is somehow broken if the range is in a filtered table?  (But only *sort of* broken, because VBA will still do the operation without complaining.)

Comment: Apparently. There's probably a dupe here somewhere. [This seems related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159073/copying-an-array-to-a-filtered-range-gives-irrational-results).

Comment: This might suggest that `D2:D4` is broken, not `A2:A4`.

Comment: [Also related here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65969051/2662901).  Slightly different examples, and nobody seems to know exactly what Excel is doing with filtered rows or why.

Comment: It looks that you completely ignore the key of the problem. It has been offered in the first comment: `(SpecialCells xlVisible)`... When try copying the range `Value` this acts like an array and works as expected only in continuous range. In case of discontinuous range it returns only **the first area**. Until the first space...

Comment: The only way I know this would work is if you would remove the filter. Yesterday I answered *copy active row and insert below even with active filter* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66275031/copy-active-row-and-insert-below-even-with-active-filter/66277566#66277566). The second procedure is backing up the filters to an array, while the third is reapplying the backed up filters. The first is showing how to use it.